# Oracle ODBC data client - C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odac

I installed Oracle 11g home edition. I read that to use Oracle data access via .NET, I must install "Oracle ODAC" from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

The readme text file mentions that  `"The files of this zip file is NOT to be installed on top of an existing Oracle Universal Installer (OUI) based Oracle Home installation"`

I don't understand. How am I supposed to get `Oracle.data.access.dll` for the existing Oracle install then?

Comment: In the Oracle installer you can enable component ODBC to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used setup.exe file to update the database and checked the option to install .net option. It worked then.